# Using data from another function

Tags: r

I have created a function in R "EffectSize" which gives me a table of data when I run it.

i.e.

```
EffectSize=function(data,conf.level,statistic){
...
}
```

and running

```
EffectSize(epidural, 0.95, "OR")
```

I get:

```
    Author    OR ln(OR) Var ln(OR)            95% CI
1    A 0.894 -0.112   0.309967  (0.3001, 2.6611)
2   B 0.908 -0.097   0.064500  (0.5519, 1.4934)
3  C 0.824 -0.194   2.130252 (0.0471, 14.3893)
4 D 0.874 -0.135   0.015054  (0.6871, 1.1115)
5     E 0.764 -0.269   0.021964  (0.5712, 1.0212)
6 F 0.328 -1.116   0.415859  (0.0926, 1.1599)
```

Now I want to create another function which uses values from this table.

I want the function to be structured in the same way so that it is:

```
InVar=function(data,conf.level,statistic){
...
}
```

Just as a bit of background to the problem, I want that

```
weight=1/varodds
muhat=sum(weight*logodds)/sum(weight)
varmuhat=1/sum(weight)
```

To achieve this I have tried to do things like

```
InVar=function(data,conf.level,statistic){
weight=1/EffectSize[,4]
...
}
```

but I am not getting any luck.

I hope I have explained the kind of thing I am after well enough and would appreciate any help you can offer.

Many thanks

Comment: EffectSize is a function not a dataframe/matrix. The way you are referencing it won't work. I would suggest reading up on R data structures and functions. http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html

Comment: It is always nice to have questions where as much as possible of the things unrelated to the problem (my function does not work) is stripped away and the things that are actually posted work (in this case break) as posted. So try to show real, minimal code instead of bloated pseudo-code - please. Put differently: I had to **read a lot** and **still had to guess** and make assumptions about the problem and how it might have happened.

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell exactly how your `EffectSize` function works, but I assume it's generating the table as a side-effect and not returning an object.

Assign the table to an object inside the function and then have the function return that object:

```
EffectSize=function(data,conf.level,statistic){
...
table <- functionThatMakesTable
return(table)
}
```

Then in your second function use `EffectSize` and extract information from the resulting table object:

```
InVar=function(data,conf.level,statistic){
weight=1/EffectSize(data,conf.level,statistic)[,4]
...
return(weight)
}
```

A cleaner approach would be to calculate the weight inside `EffectSize` and either return both the table and weight as a list or just the weight:

```
EffectSize=function(data,conf.level,statistic){
...
table <- functionThatMakesTable

print(table) # see the table in the output

weight <- 1/table[,4]

return(list(table, weight)) # or return(weight) if you just want to see the table and not use it later
}
```

Regarding your original code, as @Avinash points out, you have to apply a function to index the object it returns - you can't index the function itself.

Answer (score 2):

**To give a short answer: You cannot subset functions.**

suppose you have ...

```
dummy <- function(){
  # doing some stuff
  results <- data.frame(1:3, letters[1:3])
  return(results)
}
```

what you cannot do is the following ...

```
dummy[1,]
```

.. but that one will work ...

```
dummy()[1,]
```

---

`dummy[1,]` tries to subset the object *dummy*. BEcause dummy is a function and not matrix or an data.frame it does not support this method.

On the other hand `dummy()[1,]` works because it tries subsetting the result produced by `dummy()` instead of the function itself.

---

Therefore, I suppose that instead of this line ...

```
weight=1/EffectSize[,4]
```

**that one should work for you:**

```
weight=1/EffectSize()[,4]
```

Comment: Brilliant answer to a not-that-much question. +1!

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sorry I struggled to express what I really wanted to do but this helped me thanks.